# Focus method not working on asp.net gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, checkbox, focus

I have a web page with gridview.  I received a requirement that the first checkbox on the gridview should have the focus when the page loads.  I put the following code:

CheckBox chkBox = (CheckBox)grdMenuPublicHealth.Rows[0].FindControl("chkSelect");
//chkBox.Checked = true;
chkBox.Focus();

I put the Checked method in to make sure the checkbox was being found, and it works.  However, the Focus() method doesn't appear to be working.  Has anyone run into this before?

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the following JQuery worked:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input[type=checkbox]:first').focus();
    });
</script>
```